# Plot timedelta in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm reading in some year, time (duration) data and I want to plot a chart of year on the x axis and time (duration) on the y axis. I want the y axis to have a HH:MM:SS format. I can't figure out how to do it. Here's my code (data is synthesized, real data set is much larger).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, date2num

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2010, 2011, 2012], 
                   'Time': ['2:19:15', '2:11:16', '2:20:17']})
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

myFmt = DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

ax.plot(df['Year'], df['Time'].dt.total_seconds())

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

If I don't convert to total_seconds, I get an error. It seems like the total seconds values are being interpreted as days. I tried dividing total_seconds by 24*60*60, but that gave me a message about a 0 date. I can't persuade date2num to work for me either.

I've checked on previous similar questions, but the code no longer works.

Does anyone know how to plot Pandas timedeltas in matplotlib?

Comment: Just for those who land here by web search - there is a pending matplotlib feature-add to enable the plotting of TimeDeltas - eventually this should be added to MPL: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/19236

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the timedeltas to `datetime` with `pd.to_datetime()`. It will give everything a date in 1970, but if all you want is to plot and display then it won't matter. You then need to get rid of the `.dt.total_seconds()` too.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, date2num

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2010, 2011, 2012], 
                    'Time': ['2:19:15', '2:11:16', '2:20:17']})
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

myFmt = DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

ax.plot(df['Year'], df['Time'])

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot Result]

Comment: `TypeError: dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]`